# Is it possible to pass additional arguments to async.eachSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

is it possible to pass additional arguments or parameters to `async.EachSeries`

The method signature is : `EachSeries(arr, iterator, callback)`

and I have a method that merges email-recipients with a mail template async

```
var mergeTemplate = function(template,recipients,callback){

  async.EachSeries(recipients,processMails,callback);

};

var processMails = function(template,singleRecipient,callback){
   //...this would contain an async.waterfall of tasks to process the mail
   async.waterfall(tasks,callback);
}
```

What I would need is to pass through the template without using a "dirty" global variable...
Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: You can use an object to encapsulate multiple expressions in one entity. This is a common solution for using callbacks that take only one user-defined argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass in template without using a global variable:

```
var mergeTemplate = function(template, recipients, callback){
    async.eachSeries(recipients, processMails.bind(processMails, template), callback);
};
```

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So `processMails.bind(processMails, template)` creates a new function with `this` set to `processMails` and the first argument to this new function is `template`.

This is equivalent (but less verbose) to calling `processMails` directly like this:

```
var mergeTemplate = function(template, recipients, callback){
    async.eachSeries(
      recipients, 
      function(){
         return processMails(template);
      }, 
      callback);
};
```